# Vue.js throws multiple warnings: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got String with value ""

Tags: node.js, rest, express, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using `vue-cli` for the front-end and `express` for the backend. The processing time for my backend data is 1.7 sec and if I do the request under `mounted ()`, vue already has read the `data ()` and gives me warnings, that it is expecting other type and can't do sort etc.

**Is there a way to do this without the warnings?**

This my html part:

```
   <v-data-table
        class="ownstyle"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="orders"
    >
        <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
            <td >{{ props.item.value1 }}</td>
            <td >{{ props.item.value2 }}</td>
            ...
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

And here is the script part:

```
data () {
    return {
        headers: [
            { text: 'name1', value: 'value1', ...},
            { text: 'name2', value: 'value2', ...},
            ...
        ],
        orders: ''
    }
},

mounted () {
    ApiService.orders().then(
        response => (this.orders = response.data))
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The data-table expects the orders variable passed via `:items="orders"` to be an array. You are defining it as a string here `orders: ''`. You probably want to use `orders: []` instead.